# Using CImg and OpenCv libraries in gtk + cpp applications

Tags: c++, opencv, gtk, gtkmm, cimg

Which libraries do you recommend besides Cairo to write a professional drawing and painting application with C++?
Such as CImg, OpenCV and etc.

And is it possible to use the gtk library to design the user interface and implement the drawing and painting part of the app with other relevant libraries beside the cairo lib?
I mean i want create an GUI app with gtk windows and widgets and for example using CImg to drawing instead of cairo.
Is it possible ? How ?

Comment: Considering that GTK+ evolved as a spin-out of [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), I would assume there is strictly speaking needed nothing else. Furthermore, [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) is based on gtkmm but I don't know whether it has other dependencies as well. This may also depend on what features do you intend to include into your _professional drawing and painting application_, but mentioning OpenCV (CV like Computer Vision) let me suspect you want something else. I'm afraid that your question is too broad and unclear for a precise answer but at best an invitation for opinions...

Comment: ...which is off-topic on this site.

Comment: Do you think using the Cairo Library is enough ?

Comment: That depends on what you actually want to implement. GIMP and Inkscape are open source. You can look into their websites and source codes to get inspiration. What cairo exactly can and cannot provide is beyond my experience. However, the intro text of [libcairo](https://www.cairographics.org/) sounds quite promising.

Comment: OpenCV is **not** a library for drawing. its drawing primitives have known and easily demonstrable defects. it's a library for *computer vision*, which is why that receives little attention.